# Manipulating Matlab Structure returned by dir('./folder')

Tags: matlab

I recently updated my Matlab revision from 2007a to 2012a and I am running into a problem with some code that, on R2007a, ran just fine. Specifically concerning the structure of file names returned by `dir('./folder')`

An example:

```
X = dir('./folder');
p = X(:).name;
```

Running this code in R2007a, p contains all the filenames in that folder, however, in R2012a p only contains the name of the first file in X.names. I have also tried:

```
p = X.name;
```

and

```
p = X(:,1).name;
```

all of which do not produce the desired list of file names.

Has anyone else experienced this problem? Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: I do not have R2012 on me to test (just Octave and I'm not sure what version it emulates), but I suspect `p = {X.name}` will convert `p` into a cell array such that `p{i}` is the `i`th path.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee: I see you thought of the same thing. Yes, it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm surprised that R2007a should have been able to do that. Anyway, what has always worked is to catenate into a cell array:

```
p = {X.name};
```

Comment: Great that works! But I don't understand why X.name is not already considered a cell array. I can accept that the syntax just works that way, but is there any specific reason why brackets are necessary? If X.name is a cell array, then what information do they add?

Comment: @GPSmaster: `X` is an array of structures, `X(i).name` is a string - not a cell array. `X.name` returns multiple output arguments that are catenated with the curly brackets, as if you had written `{X(1).name, X(2).name,` etc.

Comment: For example, the class() function works on every Object I have come across but, in the case of X.name, it will only return "cell" if X.name is surrounded by brackets. Otherwise it returns an error.

Comment: Oh I see. I didn't see your response when I posed that. Thanks for the explanation! But one last question, Is X.name without brackets an object?

Comment: @GPSmaster: Again, the problem is that calling a field on an array of structures returns multiple arguments. Class only takes a single input, that's why it errors. You can either can call `class(X)`, which shows that it's a structure, or `class(X(1).name)` which returns `char`.

Comment: Ok I see. So X.name should be thought of as a function that returns a set of char arrays and by adding brackets, the char arrays are concatenated into a cell array of chars. I think I get it now. Thank you!